# extract name of atribute of class

Tags: xslt

how show title attribute?

I would like to extract data from the **@name**.

```
<specs>
<spec name="b_homologation">1</spec>
<spec name="s_homologation_type">mo</spec>
<spec name="b_xl">0</spec>
<spec name="b_runflat">0</spec>
<spec name="s_consumption">e</spec>
<spec name="i_noise">72</spec>
<spec name="s_grip">c</spec>
</specs>
```

the result has to be:

```
<field name="b_homologation">1</field>
<field name="s_homologation_type">mo</field>
...
```

Thanks.

**edit:**

```
  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:call-template name="field">
      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="field">
    <xsl:param name="name" select="name()" />
    <xsl:param name="value" select="text()" />
      <field name="{$name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
      </field>
  </xsl:template>
```

And result is(not correct):

```
<field name="specs">1mo00e72c</field>
```

Comment: This looks like it's just an identity transformation overridden to rename `spec` elements as `field`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, there's no need to mess around with named templates and parameters here, it's just a plain identity transform with tweaks:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <!-- copy input to output verbatim ... -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ... except spec elements, whose name changes to field -->
  <xsl:template match="spec">
    <field><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></field>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will produce

```
<specs>
<field name="b_homologation">1</field>
<field name="s_homologation_type">mo</field>
<field name="b_xl">0</field>
<field name="b_runflat">0</field>
<field name="s_consumption">e</field>
<field name="i_noise">72</field>
<field name="s_grip">c</field>
</specs>
```

You can use the same trick if you want to rename the root `specs` element to something like `fields`, but you can't leave it out completely if you want your output to be well-formed XML.

Answer (score -1):

something like this? Didn't test it, can include some mini-bugs :)

```
<xsl:template match="spec" >
    <xsl:call-template name="outputToXml" >
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="@name" />
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="." />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="outputToXml" >
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:param name="value" />

    <xsl:text>&lt;field name="</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
        <xsl:text>"&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
        <xsl:text>&lt;/field&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```